# Why do so many files in IntelliJ have the nginx icon?

Tags: intellij-idea

I noticed that many of my files had their icons changed and IntelliJ's auto-formatting is broken for them. I don't know what I did before it happened because I didn't notice it right away.

[image: NGINX Icons]

The "File Types" config seems fine to me:
[image: File Types]

If I rename one the affected files, the icon changes back to the correct one but since I don't want to rename all of those files I wonder if someone here has an idea how to fix this in a better way.
I'm using IntelliJIdea 2020.1

Comment: Does IDE restart help? Does it help if you disable 3rd plugins (Nginx)? Could be a plugin bug.

Comment: Restarts did not help, also disabling nginx plugin-restarting-enabling-restarting did not help :(